# vulkan compute shader direct access to CPU allocated memory

Tags: vulkan

Is there any way in vulkan computer shader to bind specific location in CPU memory, So that I can directly access it in shader language.

For example, if I have a variable declaration `int a[]={contents........};`, can I bind the address of `a` to say binding location 0 and then access in glsl something like this

```
layout(std430,binding = 0) {
int a[];
}
```

I want do this because to I don't want spend time on writing and reading from buffer.

Comment: That's what an SSBO *is*: accessing RAM (through a VkBuffer, which is bound to memory). How would this be any different from an SSBO?

Comment: @NicolBolas VkBuffer has its own different address. I want VkBuffer or whatever to be in address which I want. So that I have no need to write data to buffer.

Comment: "*VkBuffer has its own different address.*" What do you mean by "address"? In your C code, the `VkBuffer` object is a pointer, yes, but its just pointing to a C object that represents a buffer in Vulkan. The address of that object is not like an address in GPU-accessible device memory.

Comment: "*I don't want spend time on writing and reading from buffer.*" Why would whatever it is you're trying to do be slower than an SSBO? "writing and reading from a buffer" is *how* you write and read from memory. The buffer *represents* the memory. The GPU is not doing any special indirection when it uses a buffer.

Comment: @NicolBolas I asking is there any way to set VkBuffer's pointer to location I want? I want VkBuffer to be my C object

Comment: Lastly, when you say "RAM" are you talking about CPU memory? Are you asking if the GPU can directly access a CPU allocation that you make outside of the Vulkan API? "*I asking is there any way to set VkBuffer's pointer to location I want?*" Again, I don't understand exactly what you mean here. Binding the buffer to a GPU-accessible allocation is *how* you "set its pointer".

Comment: By RAM I mean CPU memory. Are you asking if the GPU can directly access a CPU allocation that you make outside of the Vulkan API?Yes.    I want something like cudaHostGetDevicePointer in CUDA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you cannot make the GPU access memory that Vulkan did not allocate itself for the GPU. The exception to this are external allocations made by other APIs that themselves are allocating GPU-accessible memory.

Just taking a random stack or global pointer and shoving it at Vulkan isn't going to work.

> I want something like `cudaHostGetDevicePointer` in CUDA

What you're asking for here is not what that function does. [That function](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_ga475419a9b21a66036029d5001ea908c.html) takes a CPU pointer to CPU-accessible memory *which CUDA allocated for you* and which you previously mapped into a CPU address range. The pointer you give it must be within a mapped region of GPU memory.

You can't just shove a stack/global variable at it and expect it to work. The variable would have to be within the mapped allocation, and a global or stack variable can't be within such an allocation.

Vulkan doesn't have a way to reverse-engineer a pointer into a mapped range of device memory back to the `VkDeviceMemory` object it was mapped from. This is in part because Vulkan doesn't have pointers to allocations; you have to use `VkDeviceMemory` object, which you create and manage yourself. But if you need to know where a CPU-accessible pointer was mapped from, you can keep track of that yourself.

Comment: Sooo, `cudaHostGetDevicePointer` is pretty much [vkMapMemory](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkMapMemory.html)?

Comment: @user369070: No. It's merely a way to get a pointer to some device memory if you have a pointer into host-accessible memory mapped from that device memory. That is, mapping must have *already* happened for this call to work.

Answer (score 0):

> I want do this because to I don't want spend time on writing and reading from buffer.

Vulkan is exactly for people that do want to spend time managing how the data flows. You might want to consider some rapid prototyping framework or math library instead.

> Is there any way in vulkan computer shader to bind specific location in CPU memory

Yes, but it won't save you any time.

Firstly Vulkan does allow allocation of CPU memory via `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT|VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT`. So you could allocate your stuff in that `VkDeviceMemory`, map it, do your CPU stuff in that address space, and then use it on GPU.

Second way is via using the `VK_EXT_external_memory_host` extension, which allows you to import your pointer into Vulkan as `VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_HOST_ALLOCATION_BIT_EXT`. But it is involved in its own way, and the driver might say "nope", so you are back to square one.